# Making my first wordpress template

Tags: php

I making my first Wordpress template. I used this code to add only the h1 to the page.

```
<?php $title = get_the_title($post->ID); echo $title; ?>
```

But is there a code. That only add the post to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to show the content of a post or a page:

```
<?php the_content() ?>
```

Use this code to show the title of a post or a page:

```
<?php the_title() ?>
```

This page can be useful if you are new to designing WP themes:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Site_Design_and_Layout

Here is a list of the template-tags you can use in your template to show info like date, nvaigation, comment-field, comment-form, title, excerpt, content etc:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags

good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'only add the post to the page' I'm assuming you are looking for `<?php the_content(); ?>`

I suggest that you read the Wordpress documentation on developing your own templates - [HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates) and more specifically - [HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)